# How to use angular js with webstorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I created new project and selected "Angular JS" as project type in webstorm.

Now webstorm has created a project for me like this:

[image]

I have added angular.js as a dependent javascript library.

When I open the `index.html` file, it has below code:

```
  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
```

The code is referring to angular js files which are present in folder called as `bower_components`, but the webstorm has not created any such folder automatically. Due to this when I created a file called `app1.js` and trying to write some angular js code the auto-completion is not working at all.

[image]

What is the correct way of creating the projects in webstorm for Angular JS?

Earlier I tried with creating a simple project rather than Angular Js project but still had issue with auto-completion. The details are given in this post : [How to create a simple angular js project in webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798073/how-to-create-a-simple-angular-js-project-in-webstorm)

**Update:**

Thanks to Daniel, now the issue of bower components is solved. But still the auto-completion is not working when I try to do for code `webstorm.controller`, please see below screenshot, how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you ran 'bower install' yet?

Comment: @deceze, both are different projects. One is created as a simple blank project and another as angular js project.

Comment: @daniel, can you please tell me how do I install that? I am new to webstorm & angular js both.

Comment: You need to download node.js, which comes with the npm package manager. Then you need to install bower via. npm, then run bower install

Comment: @daniel,  am using ubuntu machine, can you please help with the steps how can I do that?

Comment: 1. Install node (https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions), 2. run 'npm install -g bower', 3. run 'npm install' inside your project directory 4. run 'bower install' inside your project directory

Comment: @daniel, Thanks a lot daniel, I am able to install `node js` and `bower`. But still the auto-complete feature is not working as expected, can you please tell me if there is any other setting that I need to do? The auto-complete for `angular.module` worked but when I started accessing the controller then there is no auto-complete option for it.

Comment: run `bower install` in the project directory

Comment: @AlexanderElgin, I already did that as per daniel's comment.

Comment: @daniel, I am facing issue in windows machine when I run the `npm install` command, can you please take a look at my new post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826245/failed-at-the-angular-seed0-0-0-postinstall-script-bower-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Angular methods completion doesn't currently work, please follow [WEB-14134](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14134) for updates

Comment: Thanks lena, I was thinking there is some problem with my configuration, I will follow the bug to see when it gets fixed.