# Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm

I am getting below exception when I run the command `npm install` from my project directory in `webstorm` IDE.

```
bower angular-route#~1.4.0      ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\sample5\npm-debug.log
```

I have already installed `node js` and installed `bower` using command `npm install -g bower`.

Please help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23179102/1586880

Comment: @daniel, Thanks a lot, yes seems to be git issue, I am checking it. But in my ubuntu machine I do not have any git, but still the command worked. Can you please tell me is this issue is OS dependent? In Windows is GIT is must for working?

Comment: git is needed for node.js itself, but yeah in windows you need to put the location in the environment variables as it doesn't automatically detect where it is

Comment: @daniel, Thanks a lot, the issue is with git only. It is solved now